# Difference between n-dimensional of length m and m-dimensional of length n?

Tags: representation

With respect to classifying the MNIST digits I've seen the input representation referred to as both a [one-dimensional array of 748 elements](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J1enDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT164&lpg=PT164&dq=why+is+mnist+784+dimensional+rather+than+1+dimensional+with+784+elements&source=bl&ots=Wte1O2MuO6&sig=ACfU3U1aWRIAVTi4c7d83XzMlaS4WEjN3Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM6JrV7ZHoAhV1aRUIHZAiD_EQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=why%20is%20mnist%20784%20dimensional%20rather%20than%201%20dimensional%20with%20784%20elements&f=false) and a [784-dimensional vector](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html).

Are these perspectives always interchangeable, or is there a material difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

They are just transposed version.

Often input shape wont matter for informational (performance purposes yes) what will matter is the information inside these vectors and wether its discriminative enough.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those are equivalent in any practical sense. But for MNIST, the data is 'really' a 2D array of values. The 2D spatial relationship is important. You don't have to use it, but will probably do better if you do. Element 0 and 28 are as related as 0 and 1, but this isn't captured by a simple dense layer. That's why these are frequently reshaped as 28x28 and convolutional 2D layers are used.